# SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to drop all rows containing NaNs and encode all the categorical variables inside of data.

I wrote a function that looks like

```
def preprocess_data(data):

    data = data.dropna()
    le = LabelEncoder()
    data['car name'] = le.fit_transform(data['car name'])

    return data
```

which takes a dataframe and returns a processed data.
Running this function gives me a warning that says:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I don't quite get which part of my code is causing this and how to fix it.

Comment: What are you passing to `preprocess_data`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you tell pandas that `data` it is its own data frame (and not a slice) by using:

```
def preprocess_data(data):

    data = data.dropna().copy()
    le = LabelEncoder()
    data['car name'] = le.fit_transform(data['car name'])

    return data
```

A more detailed explanation here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17476

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give more information and / or the problem is not in the method.
The following code does not produce warning.

```
def preprocess_data(data):

    data = data.dropna()
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    data['car name'] = le.fit_transform(data['car name'])
    return data


preprocess_data(pd.DataFrame({'car name': ['nissan', 'dacia'], 'car mode': ['juke', 'logan']}))

#   car mode  car name
# 0     juke         1
# 1    logan         0
```